# How can i add minutes to a date in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I use the following:

```
  --start-time $(date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ") --end-time $(date -u +"%Y-%m- 
        %dT%H:%M:%SZ")
```

So the end and start time are the same.
I want to make the endtime 5minutes more that the start time.
How can i do this ?

Comment: why did yo use the -f instead of stick to the -u ? So i should change the start-time to use the -f switch as it is  a bit clearer

Comment: `(get-date) + '0:5'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add minutes in powershell

```
$date = Get-Date #current Date and time
$addminutes = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(5) # adding 5 minutes to current date and time
```